# Implement Interface in custom "Connected Web Part" to provide "Filter Values"

Tags: web-part

**Question 1.1**

What interface do I need to implement into my custom web part, to make it a provider for "filter values" for a normal XsltListViewWebPart?

**Answer**
- IWebPartParameters

> **"XSLT List View Web Part"**
>   "Provider Connections - IWebPartTable, IWebPartRow
>  Consumer
>   Connections - IWebPartParameters"

...from page 385 from "SharePoint 2010 Web Parts in Action",
[online pdf reader](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781935182771/out-of-the-box-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2010/app01lev1sec2#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE5MzUxODI3NzEvMzg1)

**Question 1.2**

And how do I implement it correctly?

```
public class ProjectPhases : WebPart, IWebPartParameters 
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // Something
    }
    public void GetParametersData (ParametersCallback callback)
    {
        // ??
    }
    public void SetConsumerSchema (PropertyDescriptorCollection schema)
    {
        // ??
    }
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection Schema
    {
        // ??
    }
}
```

**Question 2.1**

Does this Interface implement a method returning a CAML query?

**Answer** - I doubt it, because of the generic name of the interface, *"IWebPartParameters"*

**Question 2.2**

In what form do I send the data to the consuming XsltListViewWebPart which makes it filter the list?

**The goal**

This is how I want any XsltViewWebPart acting as a "consumer" to act, once my Custom Web Part acts as a "provider":
[image: Wanted end result]

---

**What I've learned so far:**

I've understood that there are some filter Web Parts available in SharePoint Enterprise, sadly I'm working with Server Edition. These Web Parts reside inside the `Microsoft.Office.Server.FilterControls.dll`.

A method of importance i belive: 
*SetConnectedFilterProvider* - Sets the IWebPartParameters instance from the filter provider to the DataFormWebPart. (Inherited from DataFormWebPart.)
[msdn XsltListViewWebPart Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.xsltlistviewwebpart_methods.aspx)

---

**Some links providing info about "Connected Web Parts"**

- [Walkthrough: Creating Connectable Web Parts in SharePoint Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx)
- [How to build a consumer web part in SharePoint 2010 using IWebPartParameters that works with HTML Form Web Part and Filter Web Parts?](http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2011/03/how-to-build-a-consumer-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-using-iwebpartparameters-that-works-with-html-fo.html)
- [Connecting XsltListViewWebParts together in code](http://jcapka.blogspot.com/2010/06/connecting-xsltlistviewwebparts.html)
- [Programmatically connect two ListViewWebParts to Filter based on value of Provider Web Part](http://kvdlinden.blogspot.com/2011/02/programmatically-connect-two.html)
- [Declarative Fun: Provisioning Web Part Connections in sandboxed solutions](http://blogs.code-counsel.net/Wouter/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=161)
- [Negotiate Between Web Parts](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2006/02/01/negotiate-between-web-parts.aspx)
- [Implementation of IWebPartParameters web part](http://blog.mindbusiness.de/blog/2011/09/05/implementation-of-iwebpartparameters-web-part/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already referring to (my) the SharePoint 2010 Web Parts in Action book, you have all your answers on page 349 "Connect using IWebPartParameters".

You basically work with a set of property descriptors that each has a type, name and value. This is only parameters you're sending from the provider to the consumer. The consumer tells what properties it can accept (type and name) and the provider says it can deliver properties (type and name) with values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm honored that the famous Wictor Wilén himself takes his time to answer my question. I'm continuing reading your book and trying to understand the plumbing so I can write the providing interface myself.